# Help please, I'm Newbie. About payment application on Visual Basic 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, payment

I want to build one project a simple payment information for my little shop.

Any body can help me? I'm still not understanding about Visual Basic 2010. 
I'm developed in Pascal 7.0 Ago..

The application simple using some textbox for Input and calculate in output textbox by pressing button.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear which part you having trouble with.

But you'll need to understand

1. Creating a project
2. Adding controls to a form
3. Event handling
4. Referring to controls on the form from your code

You might want to [start with a quick tour of the IDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms165088.aspx) and then move on to [this turtorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/dd435692.aspx) The [new to development site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789097) may be helpful down the road.

You might also find the videos from [this youtube user](http://www.youtube.com/user/TeachMeComputer) helpful.